# Recursively search JSON and delete certain sub objects

Tags: javascript

I need to search a complex json object recursively, and delete the object associated with any key that starts with "_".

So far, I have:

```
sanitize: function(json){
    for(var i in json){
        if(json[i]){
            if(i.substring(0,1) == "_")
                delete json[i];
            else
                this.sanitize(json[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(json);
    return json;
}
```

I exceed the maximum call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Try using your own array, and also make sure the subobjects aren't circular references, and also make sure they're objects.

```
function sanitize(json) {
    var stack = [];
    var done = [];

    do {
        for(var x in json) {
            if(x.charAt(0) === '_') {
                delete json[x];
            } else if(done.indexOf(json[x]) === -1 && typeof json[x] === 'object') {
                stack.push(json[x]);
                done.push(json[x]);
            }
        }
    } while(json = stack.pop());
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something? When I return json after this function, its undefined

Comment: What is the `stack` variable doing?

Comment: @gonzoc0ding: It's passed by reference, you don't return anything. Just pass in an object, and the object gets sanitized in place.

Comment: @Jeff: It's a replacement for the regular call stack.